# DB GLOBAL_NAME in Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

If I need database global name, so in ORACLE (sql) I can obtain this information in this way:

> SQL> select global_name from global_name;
>
> > RESULT:
> >
> > TESTDB.CZ.GRECA

In web application I can obtain this information in this way (for example in Controller):

> InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName();

But my question is … exists some similar way in HIBERNATE (hql)? I could not find anything in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a native SQL query in hibernate. See the docs [for Scalar Queries here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html#d5e3574).